# How to write $stmt in log from PHP script?

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I don't know PHP scripts. Basically am an iPhone app developer. I want to send Apple Push Notifications from server. Am following this tutorial for APNS process http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2. I have using api.php script to store the values in MySQL tables.

I want to know what is happening in below lines.

```
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM usersTable WHERE udid = ? LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->execute(array($udid));
        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        writeToLog('handleMessage SELECT * FROM usersTable WHERE udid = ? LIMIT 1');

        if ($user !== false)
        {
            // Put the sender's name and the message text into the JSON payload
            // for the push notification.
            $payload = $this->makePayload($user->nickname, $text);

            writeToLog('handleMessage Payload: ' . $payload);

            // Find the device tokens for all other users who are registered
            // for this secret code. We exclude the device token of the sender
            // of the message, so he will not get a push notification. We also
            // exclude users who have not submitted a valid device token yet.
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM usersTable WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'");
            $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
            $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
                writeToLog('handleMessage Tokens: ' . $tokens); // It is showing value like 'Array'

            // Send out a push notification to each of these devices.
                    // If the senders secret code is differ from registered secret code this foreach loop won't execute
            foreach ($tokens as $token)
            {
                writeToLog('Sending payload and token to addPushNotification Function');
                writeToLog('token in foreach loop token: ' . $token);
                $this->addPushNotification($token, $payload);
            }
        }
```

I hope can anyone understand this PHP script's functionality. How to print $stmt and $tokens in log file? Can you please explain me what is going on these lines? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NiftyDude can you please explain me the functionality of the lines in my questiong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: writeToLog is a function that handles that. Find it in your code and you'll be onto a winner

Comment: @KasiaGogolek Thanks. I have tried this writeToLog('handleMessage stmt: ' . $stmt); but nothing has printed in the log file. Can you please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $stmt is an object so it can't be turned into string, the code above should however print some output into string. is the log file just empty? have you got correct permissions on it?

Answer (score 0):

Change

`writeToLog('handleMessage Tokens: ' . $tokens);`

to

`writeToLog('handleMessage Tokens: ' . print_r($tokens, 1));`

Comment: Thank you Mr.Roman for your answer. Can you please explain the code and its functionality. Because, i don't know the PHP script. Can you please help me to understand the work of the above line in the php script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes you are right Mr.Roman and thanks. But code wise can't understand what is happening in these lines $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT device_token FROM usersTable WHERE secret_code = ? AND device_token <> ? AND device_token <> '0'"); 
            $stmt->execute(array($user->secret_code, $user->device_token));
            $tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);  Can you please tell me these lines function? Thanks.

Comment: And can you please tell me how to print $stmt from these codes?

Comment: Here, you select device_token of other users with similar secret_code, except user with UDID equal $udid. To output something, use print_r() or var_dump() functions.